# Is this the most appropriate place to ask questions about Internet infrastructure?

Tags: discussion

I have some questions about the roles of ISPs, DNS, how packets work, etc.

**For example:** What service do ISPs actually provide?

I'm trying to categorically distinguish between transit ISPs and regular ISPs, Tier 1 networks, what an "IP backbone" is, what factors determine the "speed" of the Internet outside cable type, length, and an ISP's arbitrary rate-limiting as per their consumer offerings (and not merely the speed that users receive, but the theoretical maximum speed).

I looked at the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) for the various computer/programming-based SE sites (SO, Programmers, IT Security, Server Fault, Theoretical CS, etc.) and this place seems the most appropriate, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: "transit ISP" and "regular ISP" don't mean anything, and a lot of these terms are marketing terms.   You don't have particularly bad questions in a general sense, but they're not good on SE sites.  I'm not sure what the best option for you is.

Answer (score 6):

**This isn't the correct place either.**

We mainly focus on questions that solve practical problems.

Your example questions are *far* too broad to be answered and would depend on quite a few assumptions. For example: country, definition of ISP, infrastructure and more.

If you *did* provide enough information for us to answer your question it would in all likelihood be `Too Localized` instead, and still not solve a practical problem.

I can't say that this question belongs on any SE site that I'm familiar with.

Comment: *"I cant say that this question belongs on any SE-site that I'm familiar with."*  :'(

Comment: @stoicfury Unfortunately, we can't have a site for everything :/